# x-www-form-urlencoded response ignored by WCF Service call

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, channelfactory

I am calling a SOAP service in the following way

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ServiceUri"));
ChannelFactory<IServiceInterface> factory = new ChannelFactory<IServiceInterface>(binding, address);
ISecPay3DSecure channel = factory.CreateChannel();

string rawResponse = channel.MethodName(params);
```

I generated the `IServiceInterface` by using WSDL.exe thus:

```
wsdl /si https://serviceUri
```

I then marked the generated interface with the `[ServiceContract]` and `[OperationContract]` attributes.

when I call the `channel.MethodName(..);` method it appears to work fine, but the string it is supposed to return is always `null`, I have fired up fiddler and can see that actually the service is responding correctly and it seems that the problem lies with the channel is simply not dealing with the response correctly, thus:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 11 Sep 2014 08:48:02 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: Keep-Alive

529
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Body><ns1:ServiceRequestResponse soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/">
<ServiceRequestReturn xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">/">?valid=true&amp;test_status=true&amp;tra....
```

presumably I am missing something in the channel configuration?

any pointers would be gratefully recieved

I have also tried adding a `ClientMessageInspecor` to see what is actually going on and again the 
`System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message reply` does have the data in. but once it is returned to the caller it has been set to null..

thanks

Answer (score 0):

seems it was because I had omitted the     `[return: System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute("NameOfSoapElement")]`
attribute from the interface method